# What's the Java Bean property name for method getCustomerID()?

Tags: java, javabeans

What's the correct Java Bean property name for method getCustomerID()?

I've tried customerID, customerId, CustomerId and customerid. None seem to work. Do I have to rename the Java method to get it to work?

UPDATE: I was getting stack traces from all four versions of the property name in my JSP code.  I failed to read the one for customerID fully - the problem was elsewhere.  Answer below accepted.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking about how to write in camelCase?

Comment: No @4castle, I just work in an area where ID is usually fully capitalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property name should be: `customerID`

Comment: @4castle Ideally yes, but as OP said his method name is `getCustomerID()` where `Id` is `ID`.

Comment: @downvoter what's the reason for downvote?

Comment: customerID does actually work - I've now actually read the full stack trace - the problem was elsewhere... apologies!

Comment: @uncoolbob If it works, can you please mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: They may have downvoted just to allow the OP to delete their question if they so choose.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee yes, sorry, I upvoted it, but that wasn't enough I see now.